# Limit of a characteristic function

Tags: limits, probability-theory

Take function $ f(n) = e^{\lambda n(e^{iu}-1)}$, how can we compute  $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n) \quad?$$ $i =\sqrt{-1}$, and $\lambda$ is the parameter for a Poisson random variable.

Comment: dependends on $u $, it will be zero or one

Comment: I will assume that $\lambda > 0$. If $u \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}$, then $e^{iu} - 1 = 0$ and the limit is $1$. Otherwise, $\operatorname{Re}(e^{iu}-1) < 0$ and hence the limit is zero. Combining altogether, $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \exp\{\lambda n (e^{iu} - 1) \} = \mathbf{1}(u \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}). $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ to rewrite $f(n)$ like this:

$$ f(n) = e^{\lambda n(e^{iu}-1)}$$

$$ = e^{\lambda n(\cos(u)+i\sin(u)-1)} $$

$$ = e^{\lambda n(\cos(u)-1)+i\cdot\lambda n\sin(u)} $$

Apply the exponent property $e^{x+y}=e^x\cdot e^y$:

$$ = e^{\lambda n(\cos(u)-1)}\cdot e^{i\cdot\lambda n\sin(u)} $$

Apply Euler's formula again on the second term:

$$ = e^{\lambda n(\cos(u)-1)}\cdot \left( \cos(\lambda n\sin(u))+i\sin(\lambda n\sin(u))\right) $$

Now split into real and imaginary parts:

$$f(n) = \left(e^{\lambda n(\cos(u)-1)}\cos(\lambda n\sin(u)\right) + i\cdot\left(e^{\lambda n(\cos(u)-1)}\sin(\lambda n\sin(u))\right)$$

Now the problem is simpler since you can take the limit on each part individually.

Comment: When u is a multiple of 2$\pi$, then f(n) = e $^{i\lambda n sin u}$, how should I take its limit?

Comment: If $u$ is a multiple of $2\pi$ then the function becomes constant $f(n)=1$ for all $n$ so the limit is $1$. Otherwise, the expression inside the exponential approaches $-\infty$ so the limit is zero.

Comment: actually, the u is the argument of a characteristic function of a random variable. So we still need to consider two separate cases depending on whether u is a multiple of 2$\pi$ or not. Right?